# How do you make an animated mist / smoke with lights that go through it and interact with it?

Tags: light, volumetrics, photorealism

I want to do a small patch of mist or smoke, and have lights go through it and light it up, in an animation.

I've seen the mist option directly in the interface, but as far I know it creates mist that doesn't interact with light.

I've seen the volumetric scattering in the compositor, which give great results, but you can only apply it to the entire scene to the best of my knowledge. I want it to be in particular area.

How would you go about that?

Here's an example : 
[image]

http://il5.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/15120553/thumb/1.jpg

You see the different lights affect the smoke / mist just like in real life, and some of the light goes through it.

Comment: Could you provide some screenshots/video samples? What renderer you want to use for this?

Comment: I edited my question to add a picture, and I want to use cycle render.

Comment: Do you want static background lights or animated mesh lights flying trough the smoke?

Comment: The lights will move and animate

Comment: Ok, I'll make an answer in couple of minutes with animated mesh lights.

Comment: Did you managed to make trough my answer?

Comment: Yes that's exactly the effect I was looking for. I will have to go through it this weekend  to reproduce the effect, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Final result:

[image: Final]

### First thoughts:

This is pretty complex setup and very demanding for the hardware. It's made using Cycles. You should have some knowledge in such fields as:

- creating smoke,
- setting up materials,
- render layers,
- basic compositing.

Final result is made with low settings.

### Scene setup:

First of all we need to setup up our scene.

1. Crank up **Volume Light Paths**. I've used 4. Higher values gives you better light scattering trough smoke. This step is essential for the whole thing.

[image: 1]

2. Make **Environment** color black, or whatever you need in your case.

### Object setup:

In my scene I've used two Ngon filled **Circles**, one for the light, and second for the **Smoke Flow**. One **Empty** for **Force Field**. **Cube** for **Smoke Domain**.

[image: 2]

### Light:

Small **Circle** behind **Smoke Domain** with **Emission shader**. It could be **Sphere** or anything else.

This is node setup I've used for it:

[image: 3]

### Smoke Flow:

Again it's **Circle**, and again you can use different object. If you for example want to have really dense smoke, you can use **Sphere** for it.

*Note 1: Remember to turn off view and render of this mesh in **Outliner** or assign to it **Transparent Shader**!*

Set **Temp Diff.** really low to keep smoke in place. In this case it's **0.01**.

*Note 2: Denser smoke will need higher **Volume Light Paths** and/or smaller smoke material **density** (we will get to it).*

[image: 4]

### Smoke Domain:

This is two step process.

**1. Smoke Domain setup:**

Nothing special here. Only **Noise Method** is worth mentioning, lower setting will give you smoother smoke.

[image: 5]

**2. Smoke Domain material:**

This is almost default material after using **Quick Smoke**, with addition of **Brightness/Contrast node**, which gives us harder and wither feel. Also default **density** value is decreased (this is connected to *Smoke Flow Note 1* from above).

[image: 5]

### Force Field:

To make some smoke movement I've used **Force Field** > **Turbulence**. I like to stop smoke flow then move it by a force in such cases. **Force field** is assigned to an **Empty**.

[image: 7]

### Render Layers and Composite:

To make some light blur and streaks you will need to move light emitter to another layer.

In this case I've moved my **light mesh** to second layer and kept other object on first layer then made two **Render Layers**. First Smoke, which is rendering first layer, and second - Light which is rendering second layer.

[image: 8] [image: 9]

After final rendering, go to **Composite** nodes and make this setup. This is just blurred out light with streaks and gamma correction of smoke and light.

[image: 10]

### Final thoughts:

As I said at the beginning, this isn't easy if you're new to Blender. You can find any information related to techniques used here or you can just ask me and I will extend this as needed.

You need to have in mind that values used in this particular setup will vary in any other. Things like density, emission strength, smoke resolution, volume light paths etc. could be much different then these.

Check my blend file. Load it, check it, quick rewrite it.

### Blend file:

[image]

### Edit:

You need to use for this [filmic-blender](https://sobotka.github.io/filmic-blender/). You should always use it.

Comment: @Natasha post your result by editing your question and we will see what's wrong.

Comment: Just did, as you can see it's getting there but not there yet.

Comment: @Natasha please upload file to: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ it's hard to tell what it could be just from screenshot.

Comment: @Natasha ok, I think I know what's the problem, are you using Filmic Blender for Color Management? If not - you should. I have used it in this case and forget to mention it as it is somewhat must have for any photo realism approach.